# Selecting information using ID from select in same query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,

`professors:`

[image: professors]

and `classes:`

[image: classes]

I want to execute a query by by using a string that represents a professor's name and then select the rows from classes whose id matches the id of the queried professor but all in a single query. I can't figure out a shorthand way of doing this without doing two queries, selecting the id first and then selecting the classes.
Example: `select * from classes where id = (select id from professors where name = "some professor name")`
 
 This is as far as I know syntactically incorrect but hopefully it gives you an idea of what I want.

Comment: For future reference, SHOW CREATEs are typically more useful than DESCRIBEs

Comment: I actually took a screenshot. I'm not so savy with mysql command line.

Comment: Yes, a screenshot of a DESCRIBE instead of a SHOW CREATE

Comment: I used `show columns`, whether on not those are aliases are unknown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

```
SELECT something, something
  FROM classes
 WHERE professor IN
        (  SELECT DISTINCT id 
            FROM professors
           WHERE name = 'name' 
        )
```

The trick you're missing is `IN ( )`. This allows you to construct a set of id numbers on which to search.

You may do better with

```
   WHERE name LIKE 'name%'
```

if you are not completely sure of the professor's name.

Pro tip: Avoid `SELECT *` and instead give a list of columns you need retrieved.

Comment: I actually need every column so it was fitting. Good tip though.

Comment: my pro tip is still true, because in the lifetime of a real system sometimes columns are added to or reordered in tables. You never know which of your systems will have a long life.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I guess I hadn't counted on my site being successful :)

Comment: What is the difference in performance between this and using a join if it matters?

Comment: In principle the performance difference should be minimal. But in practice it depends on table sizes and indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You want an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM classes c INNER JOIN professors p on c.id = p.id 
WHERE p.name='some professor name'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

```
SELECT 
  c.* 
FROM 
  classes c 
JOIN 
  professors p ON c.professor = c.id 
WHERE 
  p.name = "some professor name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT *
FROM CLASSES C INNER JOIN PROFESSOR P ON
     C.professor = P.ID 
WHERE P.Name = 'professor name'
```

(Or)

```
   SELECT *
   FROM CLASSES,PROFESSOR 
   WHERE CLASSES.professor = PROFESSOR.ID AND
   PROFESSOR.Name = 'professor name'
```

Comment: On the first query, it should be `ON c.professor = p.id`

Comment: The join criterion you presented the first query of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Would the second query also return the results from the professor table? I mean assuming I added a few columns to the professor table would I be selecting all of the data from it on such a query? I'm asking for performance's sake. Could I do     `SELECT *
   FROM CLASSES
   WHERE CLASSES.professor = PROFESSOR.ID AND
   PROFESSOR.Name = 'professor name' `?

Comment: For a better performance you have to go for [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)